# Submitting a form with ajax and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to add product to the database with Ajax without refreshing the page and send the data to the database but I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.` on console. How can I submit the form without refreshing the page?

Blade

```
 <form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{csrf_field()}}

           <label for="pro_name">Name</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pro_name" id="pro_name" placeholder="Enter product name">

           <label  for="category_id">Choose Category</label>
           <select name="category_name" id="category_name">
           <option value=""> --Select Category -- </option>
           @foreach ($categoryname_array as
             $data)
             <option value="{{ $data->name }}"  >{{$data->name}}</option>
             @endforeach
           </select>

           <label for="photos">Choose 5 Images</label>
           <input  "multiple="multiple" name="photos[]" type="file">

           <button type="button" onclick = "submitThisForm({{Auth::user()->id}})" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

Ajax

```
<script>
function submitThisForm(id){
    let url = "{{ route('product.store', ['id' => ':id']) }}".replace(':id', id);
    $.ajax( {
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: new FormData( this ),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    } );
    e.preventDefault();


}
</script>
```

Route

```
 Route::post('seller/product', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

Comment: You are missing the context of `this`. Try getting the form and then creating the FormData object `var form = $('form')[0]; var formData = new FormData(form);`

Comment: is that one line and where do I put it in ajax code?@porloscerrosΨ

Comment: I get this `Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined` @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Well, it's other thing. You have `e.preventDefault();` in your function, but `e is not defined`. Remove that line and add the prevent on your button tag `onclick="event.preventDefault(); submitThisForm({{Auth::user()->id}});"`

Comment: I have tried to remove `e.preventDefault();` and add that to the button but in console I see a long script like this `<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().` and it is not submitting the form @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: Yeah it is from this line `console.log(result);` @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: After changing I get `undefined` from this line `console.log(result.data);`  I just wanted to submit the data to the database but it is not submitting@porloscerrosΨ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things.

First, your route does not expect any parameters.

```
Route::post('seller/product', 'ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

So you don't need to pass it on.

```
{{ route('product.store', ['id' => ':id']) }} // remove , ['id' => ':id']
```

Then, since you are using jquery, you can handle the ajax call on the submit method of the form.

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form submit
    var url = '{{ route('product.store' }}';
    // create the FormData object from the form context (this),
    // that will be present, since it is a form event
    var formData = new FormData(this); 
    // build the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (response) {
            // handle success response
            console.log(response.data);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            // handle error response
            console.log(response.data);
        },
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
})
```

In your form you will not need the onclick event on the button..

```
<form method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}

    <label for="pro_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pro_name" id="pro_name" placeholder="Enter product name">

    <label  for="category_id">Choose Category</label>
    <select name="category_name" id="category_name">
    <option value=""> --Select Category -- </option>
    @foreach ($categoryname_array as $data)
        <option value="{{ $data->name }}"  >{{$data->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>

    <label for="photos">Choose 5 Images</label>
    <input  "multiple="multiple" name="photos[]" type="file">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: This looks good and clean, I don't get any errors but the button is still not submitting the data to the database @porloscerros Ψ

Comment: Saving data in the database happens in the backend. It's a job for Laravel, you can't save data in the database with an ajax call. Open a new question: "How to handle the data received to save it in the database?" adding what you have in the `store` function of `ProductController`, and what are the data you receive, as well as your models and database structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<script>
function submitThisForm(id){
    let url = "{{ route('product.store', ['id' => ':id']) }}".replace(':id', id);
    var form_data = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm"));
    $.ajax( {
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    } );
    e.preventDefault();


}
</script>
```

Comment: I get the script like this `<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().` and the button is not submitting @BCM